# Preparing aurelia app for production

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia

I'm trying to export my aureliajs application. My `export.js` file which I'm using in command `gulp export` contains these lines:

```
// this file provides a list of unbundled files that
// need to be included when exporting the application
// for production.
module.exports = {
  'list': [
    'index.html',
    'config.js',
    'favicon.ico',
    'LICENSE',
    'jspm_packages/system.js',
    'jspm_packages/system-polyfills.js',
    'jspm_packages/system-csp-production.js'
  ],
  // this section lists any jspm packages that have
  // unbundled resources that need to be exported.
  // these files are in versioned folders and thus
  // must be 'normalized' by jspm to get the proper
  // path.
  'normalize': [
    [
      // include font-awesome.css and its fonts files
      'font-awesome', [
        '/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        '/fonts/*'
      ]
    ], [
      // include bootstrap's font files
      'bootstrap', [
        '/fonts/*',
        '/css/*'
      ]
    ], [
      'bluebird', [
        '/js/browser/bluebird.min.js'
      ]
    ], [
      'cropperjs', [
        '/dist/cropper.css'
      ]
    ], [
      'moment', [
        '/**.*',
        '/locale/**.*'
      ]
    ], [
      'aurelia-validatejs', [
        '/**.*'
      ]
    ], [
      'aurelia-chart', [
        '/**.*',
        '/**/*.js',
        '/**/*.html'
      ]
    ]
  ]
};
```

I'm having problem exporting the `aurelia-chart` plugin. No matter what I do, it never ends up copied to `export/jspm_packages/npm` folder. How to make it behave properly?

Comment: why do you need to export aurelia-chart files? They should be bundled with one of your bundles

Comment: The same goes for aurelia validatejs, however if I do not export both plugins, then after the process, when I try to open up my ap in the browser, I get 404 errors when it tries to download some needed files.